# Using jquery UI range Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using jquery UI range slider in my site, I need to create a function for when the user increases the range and a different one for when the user decreases the range, how can i do that?
thanks

```
function createRangeSliderOutOfIframe(kinorid) {
//alert("in edit");
var addRangeSlider = '<div class="rangeSlider"><p><label for="amount' + kinorid + '">Increase Range of Selection:</label></p><div id="slider-range' + kinorid + '"></div>'; //Jquery UI slider
$('#trackingInfo').append(addRangeSlider);
//$("#slider-range" + kinorid, window.parent.document).show();
var count = 0;
var result = $(this).parent();
var i;
$("#slider-range" + kinorid).slider({
    animate: true,
    step: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    value: 5,

    change: function (event, ui) {
        var currentValue = ui.value;
        alert(currentValue + "original");
        var value = $("#slider-range" + kinorid).slider("option", "value");
        alert(value+"new");
        if (ui.value >= 5) {
            //if (!$(getSelectionParentElement).parent().prev().hasClass('kSelectedA') || !$(getSelectionParentElement).children().next().hasClass('rangeSlider')) {
            alert(count);
            var add = '<span class="kSelectedA">Link</span>';

            $("#myFrame").contents().find('*').each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('kinorid') == kinorid) {
                    //alert("change");
                    if (count == 0) {
                        $(result).parent().before(add);
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    else if (count <= 5 && count != 0) {
                        result = $(this).parent();
                        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                            result = $(result).parent();
                            //test += 1;
                        }
                        $(result).parent().before(add);
                        count += 1;
                        $('#trackingInfo').append('The range of the selection was increased<br/> ');
                        alert(count);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
        if (ui.value < 5) {
            //if (!$(getSelectionParentElement).parent().prev().hasClass('kSelectedA') || !$(getSelectionParentElement).children().next().hasClass('rangeSlider')) {
            count -= 1;
            alert("in if out");
            if ($(result).children().hasClass('kSelectedA')) {
                alert("in if");
                $(result + '.kSelectedA').remove();
            }
            //alert("second if");
            //$('.kSelectedA').remove();
        }

    }
});
/* $("#amount" + cId, window.parent.document).val($("#slider-range" + cId, window.parent.document).slider("values", 0) +
" - " + $("#slider-range" + cId, window.parent.document).slider("values", 1));*/
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the jQuery UI site:

This event is triggered on every mouse move during slide. Use ui.value (single-handled sliders) to obtain the value of the current handle, $(..).slider('value', index) to get another handles' value.

Return false in order to prevent a slide, based on ui.value.

Code examples

Supply a callback function to handle the slide event as an init option.

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
Bind to the slide event by type: slide.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you. i also saw this in jquery UI site but i didnt understand how can i do have 2 different function for when the range goes higher or lower.

Comment: @Ovi, within that function make a variable to hold the current value of the slider and then write an if block that will delegate to one of two functions based on if the value of slide becomes greater or lower.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. if i do 'var currentValue = ui.value;' i get the value after it was changed, and i dont know how to get the old value in order to if it became lower or greater. i added my hole function to the original question with edit. please help. thanks

Comment: @Ovi, you need to have the variable outside of the change function, so that it gathers the current value, not the value after the event has happened. Essentially if you move the variable you'll get the value right away and then when you invoke the change function you can compare the new value to the value stored in the variable.

Comment: I know that is what i need to do, but were in my function above can i add the variable with the current value, it has to be after i do '.slider()' and then i have the change function, were can i put it, i tried every thing and i got to get this working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

use the [change event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change) provided for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.